# Можно ли сделать шаблонную функцию friend?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть класс

```
class RegularUser : public User
{
public:
    RegularUser() {}
    ~RegularUser() {}
    template <class T>
    friend void print_u(T& obj);
```

и есть функция

```
template <class T>
void print_u(T& obj)
{
    cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

Хочу сделать это функцию другом класса, но при вызове выдает ошибку

```
RegularUser user;
print_u(user);
```

Скорее всего вызываю не так, тк без вызова всё нормально

Ошибку выдает

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl print_u<class RegularUser>(class RegularUser &)" (??$print_u@VRegularUser@@@@YAXAAVRegularUser@@@Z) referenced in function _main
```

Проект разделен на 2 .cpp и 1 хедер, где описаны прототипы

Comment: https://ideone.com/Bz3lpe

Comment: Какую "ошибку"? Почему в вопросе не приведен полный текст сообщения об ошибке?

Comment: Ну нате в *вижло*: https://rextester.com/IUPTJ21023

Comment: Нет, ну какого хрена опять САМОЕ ВАЖНОЕ в вопросе не сказано сразу?!!!

Comment: Определение функции в `.cpp` засунули?

Comment: @AnT Да, один cpp для мейна, другой для реализаций

Comment: В указаном вопросе, дублем которого является ваш, есть такая причина: *Неправильная реализация шаблонного кода.

Например, реализация шаблонного кода помещена в *.cpp файл, хотя она должна находиться полностью в подключаемом *.h файле.*

Comment: Никакого отношения к `friend` ваш вопрос не имеет.

Comment: @Harry Да, прочитал уже, переместил в хедер и сработало

Comment: @AnT Ну на момент публикования вопроса, я думал, что дело именно во френд составляющей :/